# fill texture3d slice wise

Tags: c++, directx-11

I try to fill a texture3D slice wise with 2d images.
my result only gives me back the first of the 6 images like you can see in this picture:

[image: 3D cube with the texture3D texture]

to be sure that it is not a render problem like wrong uvw coordinates I also give you the picture of the uvw coordinates:

[image: uvw coordinates of the 3d cube]

**here is the code of the creation of the texture3d:**

```
if (ETextureType::Texture3D == TextureType)
{
    ID3D11Texture3D* pTexture3D = nullptr;
    D3D11_TEXTURE3D_DESC TextureDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&TextureDesc, sizeof(TextureDesc));
    TextureDesc.Width = nWidth;
    TextureDesc.Height = nHeight;
    TextureDesc.MipLevels = nMipMaps;
    TextureDesc.Depth = nDepth;
    TextureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    TextureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;

    switch (TextureFormat)
    {
        case ETextureFormat::R8G8B8A8:
        {
            TextureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
        }
        break;

        case ETextureFormat::R32FG32FB32FA32F:
        {
            TextureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
        }
        break;

        default:
        DebugAssertOnce(UNKNOWN_TEXTURE_FORMAT);
    }

    HRESULT hr = m_pD3D11Device->CreateTexture3D(&TextureDesc, nullptr, &pTexture3D);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(UNABLE_TO_CREATE_TEXTURE);
        return false;
    }

    if (bCreateShaderResourceView)
    {
        D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC SRVDesc;
        ZeroMemory(&SRVDesc, sizeof(SRVDesc));

        SRVDesc.Format = TextureDesc.Format;
        SRVDesc.Texture3D.MipLevels = TextureDesc.MipLevels;
        SRVDesc.Texture3D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
        SRVDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE3D;
        hr = m_pD3D11Device->CreateShaderResourceView(pTexture3D, &SRVDesc, &pShaderResourceView);

        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            pTexture3D->Release();

            DebugAssertOnce(UNABLE_TO_CREATE_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW);
            return false;
        }
    }

    else if (bCreateRenderTargetView)
    {
        ID3D11RenderTargetView* pRenderTargetView = nullptr;

        hr = m_pD3D11Device->CreateRenderTargetView(pTexture3D, nullptr, &pRenderTargetView);

        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            pShaderResourceView->Release();
            pTexture3D->Release();

            DebugAssertOnce(UNABLE_TO_CREATE_RENDERTARGET_VIEW);
            return false;
        }

        pView = pRenderTargetView;
    }
    *ppTexture = new CTextureDX11(TextureType, pTexture3D, pShaderResourceView, pView);
    return true;
}
```

**and also the filling part:**

```
bool CGraphicsDriverDX11::CreateTexture3DFromImageBuffers(CTexture** ppTexture, const std::vector<CImageBuffer*>* pvecImageBuffers)
{
    uint32_t nWidth = pvecImageBuffers->front()->GetWidth();
    uint32_t nHeight = pvecImageBuffers->front()->GetHeight();

    uint32_t nMipMapLevels = 1;

    bool bRet = CreateTexture(ppTexture, nWidth, nHeight, ETextureType::Texture3D, ETextureFormat::R8G8B8A8, nMipMapLevels, false, true, false, static_cast<UINT>(pvecImageBuffers->size()));

    if (bRet)
    {
        ID3D11Texture3D* pD3DTexture = static_cast<ID3D11Texture3D*>((*ppTexture)->GetTexture());

        for (size_t nImageBuffer = 0; nImageBuffer < pvecImageBuffers->size(); ++nImageBuffer)
        {
            uint32_t nIndex = D3D11CalcSubresource(static_cast<UINT>(nImageBuffer), 0, 1);

            m_pD3D11DeviceContext->UpdateSubresource(pD3DTexture, nIndex, nullptr, pvecImageBuffers->at(nImageBuffer)->GetData(), nWidth * 4, 0);

        }
    }

    return bRet;
}
```

I tried a lot... for example I changed this code to texture2DArray and it worked fine. so the mistake is not my *CImageBuffer* class. also the nDepth variable has the correct value... I think I have to use another command for *UpdateSubresource* or at least change the parameters somehow.
I also didn't find some examples in the internet.
Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the depth textures in a slice are side-by-side in a single subresource. You also need to compute how many depth images are present in a slice for a given miplevel.

This gives you the subresource index which contains the entire slice:

```
D3D11CalcSubresource(level, 0, mipLevels);
```

This gives you the number of images in a slice for a given miplevel:

```
std::max(depth >> level, 1);
```

Each image in the slice has a pitch of `D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE.RowPitch` laid out one after another in the subresource, with the total size in bytes of the slice as `D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE.DepthPitch`.

For example, here is some code from [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) trimmed down a bit to make it easier to read. It is reading the data out of a captured 3D volume texture, but the logic is the same when filling out textures.

```
    if (metadata.IsVolumemap())
    {
        assert(metadata.arraySize == 1);

        size_t height = metadata.height;
        size_t depth = metadata.depth;

        for (size_t level = 0; level < metadata.mipLevels; ++level)
        {
            UINT dindex = D3D11CalcSubresource(level, 0, metadata.mipLevels);

            D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mapped;
            HRESULT hr = pContext->Map(pSource, dindex, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &mapped);
            if (FAILED(hr))
                // error

            auto pslice = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(mapped.pData);

            size_t lines = ComputeScanlines(metadata.format, height);
            // For uncompressed images, lines == height

            for (size_t slice = 0; slice < depth; ++slice)
            {
                const Image* img = result.GetImage(level, 0, slice);

                const uint8_t* sptr = pslice;
                uint8_t* dptr = img->pixels;
                for (size_t h = 0; h < lines; ++h)
                {
                    size_t msize = std::min<size_t>(img->rowPitch, mapped.RowPitch);
                    memcpy_s(dptr, img->rowPitch, sptr, msize);
                    sptr += mapped.RowPitch;
                    dptr += img->rowPitch;
                }

                pslice += mapped.DepthPitch;
            }

            pContext->Unmap(pSource, dindex);

            if (height > 1)
                height >>= 1;
            if (depth > 1)
                depth >>= 1;
        }
    }
```